# Phase rotation in FFT?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to perform Fourier transform followed by phase rotation. Following is the code to rotate phase through trial and error. I tried to use a constant value as an angle and rotate the phase angle of my signal,

```
g = np.fft.fft(esx+1j*esy) #FFT of my complex signal       
angle = 0.4  # constant angle for phase rotation
afd = g*np.exp(-1j*angle) #phase rotation
plt.plot(afd.real)
```

Current output:
[image: current_output.png]

Is there a way to do the phase rotation more easily or find the angle to do the phase rotation?

I'm looking for an output like this:
[image: desired output signal]

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Please edit your question to clarify the goal, maybe with an example input and desired output.

Comment: Thank you I edited my post. I want to do a phase rotation to my signal given in the link.

Comment: But what does this phase rotation accomplish? According to your desired output, you want your phase to be 0 everywhere. This is what `abs` accomplishes, but you said in the first version of your question that this was not what you wanted. You want the phase change to be the same everywhere? And you want this change to be such that as many frequencies as possible have a phase of 0? Or the phase at the origin? Or...? You can’t get the phase to be 0 everywhere by using a constant phase change, because the input phases are not the same everywhere (presumably!).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't want a power spectra because it gives a fat signal. I want to find the best angle that minimizes the imaginary part of the FFT signal.  Yes, I want this change to be such that as many frequencies as possible have a phase of 0. If it is not possible to do with a constant how do I do it with a varying angle? Thanks again !

Comment: Sorry, I’m just trying to understand what this is about. The spectrum gives “a fat signal”. Are you saying that you want to apply the inverse transform after this? You are using this phase transformation as a filter of your signal? You are aware that modifying the phase in this way destroys your signal, right?

Comment: I assume that you can do statistics on your phase angles, pick the most common angle, and subtract that from all the frequency components. But there’s a good chance that the angles are distributed uniformly, and so any rotation will give you the same small amount of zero phase components.

Comment: Could you explain how to pick the common angle through statistics? or an example method. Also how do I find these phase angles through trial and error?

Comment: `np.angle(g)` gives the phase angle of your frequency-domain signal `g`, in radian. You could then compute a histogram, `h, _ = np.histogram(np.angle(g), bins=180, range=(-np.pi, np.pi))`, and find its maximum bin, `angle = np.argmax(h) / 180 * 2 * np.pi - np.pi`. But again, I don't think this will be useful unless you have a very specific signal, and I don't understand why you want to do this.